# make a custom field behave the same as WP registration email field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

I would like something like the following *(when wordpress behaves trying to register an already registered email)*, but for a custom field:

```
// Check the email address
if ( $user_email == '' ) {
    $errors->add( 'empty_email', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please type your email address.' ) );
} elseif ( ! is_email( $user_email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The email address isn&#8217;t correct.' ) );
    $user_email = '';
} elseif ( email_exists( $user_email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'email_exists', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: This email is already registered, please choose another one.' ) );
}
```

I would like the behavior for my custom field "kundnummer" where if someone enters an already existing "kundnummer" value, it should give an error that says they must pick new one.

Comment: First and foremost, where in woocommerce does your custom field appear? what code did you use to add your custom field? the code that you want to show during validation will depend on my questions

Comment: i added it with this plug-in 
https://woocommerce.com/products/custom-user-registration-fields-for-woocommerce/
its on the my-account page  and log in page

Comment: no one knows how to do this ?